# Self transfer with separate tickets at Dublin with no check-in luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dublin, self-transfer, westjet, aer-lingus

I am planning on a one-way trip from London to Toronto with a stopover in Dublin, on separate tickets. I will not have any check-in luggage. Stopover time will be about 3 hours.

So when I am in Dublin, will I have to pass through border control or will I be able to just walk to the gate for the next flight? If I had check-in luggage, would 3 hours be enough to pass through border control and recheck luggage?

My itinerary is as follows:

LHR to DUB by Aer Lingus |
Connection time 3 hours |
DUB to YYZ by Westjet (I can check into this flight on mobile).

I will not need a visa.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't need a visa for Ireland, Canada, or both?  Entering Ireland from the UK is usually quick and easy.  What is your nationality?

Comment: Canadian nationality

Comment: Good news.  So, no visa required for any of the countries involved.  This will increase your chances of success but I would still agree with the others that it is risky.

Answer (score 5):

This comes down to a "risk assessment".

Typically 3 hours is fine for a connection like this especially if you don't have checked luggage. However, if your inbound is significantly delayed or rerouted, if there hiccups at immigration, customs or security (or whatever lines you may have to go through) there is still a residual risk of missing it.

While this risk is small, the impact is large: if you miss the flight: you may have to buy a same day or next day ticket on the spot, which can be expensive. At the moment the prices for a next day ticket are about USD $650.

Personally I don't do "high value" self-connections with less than 4 hours, but that comes down to personal risk tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

Airside transfer is very limited in Dublin, it’s only possible if you both arrive at and depart from Terminal 2 (and a few other conditions which I don’t remember).

All passengers arriving in Terminal 1 will have to go through passport control (including those arriving from the UK despite Ireland and the UK being part of the Common Travel Area).

Just after passport control in the baggage reclaim hall there is a passageway towards departures.

So you should budget quite a bit of time for the passport control queue and processing. I believe you’ll also go through security, but that would most likely have been the case even if there was airside transit. No idea if you get through the normal security check-in (and it's sometimes a very long queue) or if you benefit from a shorter queue here.

Also, even if online check-in is possible, that does not mean you will necessarily get a boarding pass in all cases. There is always a risk that for some reason they will ask you to go to check-in to get your boarding pass (usually to check documentation). This is very often the case for flights to the US for instance, don’t know about flights to Canada. In that case you would need to get to departures and to the check-in desk before the check-in deadline.

While if all goes well even this last scenario is perfectly doable in less than 3 hours (probably a lot less), with a self-transfer you have to remember that if you miss the gate closing time (or, if you have to go to check-in, the closing time of check-in desks, usually much earlier), you will be considered a no-show.

While the details vary with the airline and even more with the type of fare, in many cases that means your ticket will be cancelled, and often any further flights on the same ticket will be cancelled as well (this is more frequent with traditional airlines than with low-cost airlines, no idea where WestJet lie on that matter).

This means booking and paying for a new ticket at the last minute, at last minute prices, often a lot more expensive.

Also, if that new flight is the next day, any hotels, meals and transfers to/from the airport are on you.

If the second flight had been for a short, cheap (even at the last minute) and frequent flight (like flights between London and Dublin), then it would be no issue to consider your ticket for the second flight as “throwaway”. Here the risk is quite a bit more significant, so you should probably have quite a bit more buffer.

Also remember that in addition to possible delays (or last-minute cancellations), there is also the risk that either airline will change the schedule of their flight, and that could make the connection even more risky or even outright impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Westjet use Terminal 1 at Dublin and Aer Lingus use Terminal 2 so there’s a change of terminal involved in your journey. This link seems to indicate that an airside transfer to the other terminal is possible though it also says the link is from the baggage hall, which suggest you have to pass through immigration first:

Airport Transport - Dublin Airport T2 Guide

Whether you have to go through immigration or not, I would say that 3 hours is sufficient.

Comment: But if you miss the flight you are responsible for getting to Canada, you will not get help or an alternative flight from the airline.